# duplicated values multiprocessing python

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

I'm trying to do multiprocessing with python but I have duplicated values in results files.
Could you please help me to solve that?
here is my code:

```
import itertools
from multiprocessing import Pool
from multiprocessing import Manager
import pandas as pd

PARAMS = {}
LPT_LIMIT = [4, 6, 8, 10]
HPT_LIMIT = [1.6, 1.8, 2.0]
NB_FLIGHT = [10, 30]
LPT_EXCEEDENCE = [1, 4]
HPT_EXCEEDENCE = [3, 4]

tmp = [LPT_LIMIT, HPT_LIMIT, NB_FLIGHT, LPT_EXCEEDENCE, HPT_EXCEEDENCE]
parameters = list(itertools.product(*tmp))

def toto(param):
    PARAMS['LPT_LMIT'] = param[0]
    PARAMS['HPT_LMIT'] = param[1] 
    PARAMS['NB_FLIGHT'] = param[2]
    PARAMS['LPT_EXCEEDENCE'] = param[3]
    PARAMS['HPT_EXCEEDENCE'] = param[4]
    return PARAMS

if __name__=='__main__':
    pool = Pool()
    manager = Manager()
    my_list = manager.list()
    my_list.append(pool.map(toto, parameters))
    flat_list = [item for sublist in my_list for item in sublist]
    pd.DataFrame(flat_list).to_excel('results.xlsx', index=False)
```

the results is that I have only value of 4 in HPT_EXCEEDENCE (please see attached file)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFtsO.png)

I have only HPT_EXCEEDENCE = 4 but HPT_EXCEEDENCE is 3 or 4
So I don't know what's wrong with my code

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You need to supply more information to get helpful answers. What does `toto` do? How is the results file saved?

Comment: I have modified the post, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are doing something more complex, you don't need Manager(). The problem specifically was the location of PARAMS = {}. See updated code below. This seems to get the result you want.

```
import itertools
from multiprocessing import Pool
from multiprocessing import Manager
import pandas as pd


LPT_LIMIT = [4, 6, 8, 10]
HPT_LIMIT = [1.6, 1.8, 2.0]
NB_FLIGHT = [10, 30]
LPT_EXCEEDENCE = [1, 4]
HPT_EXCEEDENCE = [3, 4]

tmp = [LPT_LIMIT, HPT_LIMIT, NB_FLIGHT, LPT_EXCEEDENCE, HPT_EXCEEDENCE]
parameters = list(itertools.product(*tmp))

def toto(param):
    PARAMS = {}
    PARAMS['LPT_LMIT'] = param[0]
    PARAMS['HPT_LMIT'] = param[1]
    PARAMS['NB_FLIGHT'] = param[2]
    PARAMS['LPT_EXCEEDENCE'] = param[3]
    PARAMS['HPT_EXCEEDENCE'] = param[4]
    return PARAMS

if __name__=='__main__':
    pool = Pool()
    my_list = pool.map(toto, parameters)
    pd.DataFrame(my_list).to_excel('results1.xlsx', index=False)
```

Comment: Upvoted, but want to note the _why_. `Pool.map` processes data in chunks to reduce parent/worker handshakes. Multiple return values from `toto` are cached before being returned to the parent. But since its the same global (well, global to each pool process) `PARAMS` being mutated and returned, that single dict, cached multiple times, will only hold the last values written when finally returned to the parent.